# R: How to create a proportion table strictly using the aggregate function?

Tags: r

I have this line of code, but do not know the command under the FUN parameter to create the table proportions:

```
list(aggregate(df[,xx], by=list(df[,yy]), FUN=proportions)
```

Comment: DId you meant `proportions`.  If you need to create proportions table, use `proportions(table(df[c('xx', 'yy')]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are creating `proportions` table, then use `table` with `proportions` (or `prop.table`)

```
proportions(table(df[c('xx', 'yy')]))
```

---

If we need to use only `aggregate`

```
transform(aggregate(xx ~ yy, df, FUN = length), prop = xx/sum(xx))
```